# Browse image in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

As the [post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vscrystalreports/thread/55c2601a-ef7a-4dce-b980-48345350100b) says,

> There is a formula in the "format graphic" dialog where you can set the image path. So you could use a discrete parameter or a datafield to set the value.

But I could not find the same in Crystal Reports 9. So how can I assign image path in Crystal Reports 9 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you get your hands on a copy of XI or later?

If there are just a few possible images, you cam insert them all and conditionally display them. There might be other solutions, depending on what database you're using, and whether you're using Crystal with .NET/Visual Studio or on its own.